# Plot SL/TP on main price chart in tradingview using Pine Script V5

Tags: plot, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have my own Pine script strategy that plots some indicators in separate window (not on the main price chart).
However, I want to draw a line for the SL/TP to be plotted on the main price chart.

I'm trying to use it with the below code, but it gets plotted on the separate window not the main price chart :(
any idea how to plot only this one on the main price chart?
`p1= plot(strategy.position_size > 0? long_stop_level : na , "SL_Long", color=color.red,style=plot.style_linebr)`

I have my own Pine script strategy that plots some indicators in separate window (not on the main price chart).
However, I want to draw a line for the SL/TP to be plotted on the main price chart.

I'm trying to use it with the below code, but it gets plotted on the separate window not the main price chart :(
any idea how to plot only this one on the main price chart?
`p1= plot(strategy.position_size > 0? long_stop_level : na , "SL_Long", color=color.red,style=plot.style_linebr)`

Answer (score 0):

copy the same script into a new indicator. Hide everything else and set `overlay=true` to the part you want to plot